# Concatenating a prop onto an Object.assign

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm using react-images and react-photo-gallery to create lightbox galleries but trying to pull the datasets dynamically. So that I don't have to repeat code a dozen times, I need to add a prop value called ProjectId to the end of an object I'm reassigning with Object.assign.

Each gallery has it's own component file which I'm importing individually. ProjectId is passed down from props depending on which project is clicked in another component. I'm using Object.assign to move that object into an empty array which I'm then able to call within the components. By using if statements, I can assign which gallery calls which dataset but there has to be an easier way.

I've tried a half dozen combinations of concatenation to add the prop onto my second value within the Object.assign without any luck. I also briefly attempted the same thing using a spread operator.

```js
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import Carousel, { Modal, ModalGateway } from "react-images";
import Gallery from "react-photo-gallery";
import { finalImages1 } from '../data/finalImagesData/finalImages1';
import { protoImages1 } from '../data/protoImagesData/protoImages1';
import { finalImages2 } from '../data/finalImagesData/finalImages2';
import { protoImages2 } from '../data/protoImagesData/protoImages2';

const ImageGallery = (props) => {
    const [currentImage, setCurrentImage] = useState(0);
  const [viewerIsOpen, setViewerIsOpen] = useState(false);
  let dataSet = [];

  const openLightbox = (event, obj) => {
    setCurrentImage(obj.index);
    setViewerIsOpen(true);
  };
  const closeLightbox = () => {
    setCurrentImage(0);
    setViewerIsOpen(false);
  };


  if(props.dataSet === 'finalImages' && props.projectId === 1) {
        let returnDataSet = Object.assign(dataSet, finalImages1);
    } else if(props.dataSet === 'protoImages' && props.projectId === 1) {
        let returnDataSet = Object.assign(dataSet, protoImages1);
    } else if(props.dataSet === 'finalImages' && props.projectId === 2) {
        let returnDataSet = Object.assign(dataSet, finalImages2);
    } else if(props.dataSet === 'protoImages' && props.projectId === 2) {
        let returnDataSet = Object.assign(dataSet, protoImages2);
    };

    return (
        <React.Fragment>
            <Gallery photos={dataSet} direction={"column"} onClick={openLightbox} />
            <ModalGateway>
          {viewerIsOpen ? (
            <Modal onClose={closeLightbox}>
              <Carousel
                currentIndex={currentImage}
                views={dataSet.map(x => ({
                  ...x,
                  srcset: x.srcSet
                }))}
              />
            </Modal>
          ) : null}
        </ModalGateway>
    </React.Fragment>
    );
};

export default ImageGallery;
```

I'd like to end up with something like this:

```js
  if(props.dataSet === 'finalImages') {
        let returnDataSet = Object.assign(dataSet, `finalImages+${props.projectId}`);
    } else if(props.dataSet === 'protoImages') {
        let returnDataSet = Object.assign(dataSet, `protoImages+${props.projectId}`);
    };
```

Whenever I try that or something similar, the component can't find the data.

Comment: What are the shapes of the objects you're working with, and what is the shape you want to end up with?

Comment: Bergi found me a solution but to answer your question, the react-photo-gallery [link]https://github.com/neptunian/react-photo-gallery inserts the images as rectangles based on some props you pass. I was just finding a way to insert specific images without doing so inline.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This has nothing to do with properties or `Object.assign`.

What you were looking for was to dynamically choose the variable name for the object that you want to extend your dataset with, and you would use

```
eval(props.dataSet + props.projectId)
```

for that. But `eval` is a horrible idea, instead use a proper lookup structure:

```
import { finalImages1 } from '../data/finalImagesData/finalImages1';
import { protoImages1 } from '../data/protoImagesData/protoImages1';
import { finalImages2 } from '../data/finalImagesData/finalImages2';
import { protoImages2 } from '../data/protoImagesData/protoImages2';

const dataSets = {
    finalImages: {
        1: finalImages1,
        2: finalImages2,
    },
    protoImages: {
        1: protoImages1,
        2: protoImages2,
    },
};
```

(You probably will want to put this object in `../data/index.js` and then import it from there).

With this structure, you can simply use

```
const ImageGallery = (props) => {
    const dataSet = dataSets[props.dataSet][props.projectId];
    …
```

Comment: That worked great, thanks! I don't believe I've used a lookup structure like that before (React-rookie). I think I get it but can you explain one quick thing? Is the key (1, 2, 3) in each dataSet related to the projectId, just related to order, something else, or just necessary and unrelated?

Comment: Also, I really appreciate the way this solution lets me clean up my ImageGallery component, eliminating all the specifics and moving them into data/index.js that only exists for said specifics.

Comment: It's two nested lookup maps, the outer one keyed by the data set name and the inner one keyed by the project id. Here I used object literals, but you could have used `Map`s as well. An alternative would be to provide a function `getDataset(name, projectId)`, which internally may use a similar lookup tabe or also lazy-load the right json file or something.

Comment: Ah got it. Much appreciated.